# Instance applicative on datatype `List`

Tags: haskell, applicative

The Haskell book Haskell Programming from First Principles has an exercise which asks me to instance `Applicative` on the datatype `List`:

```
data List a =
  Nil
  | Cons a (List a)
  deriving (Eq, Show)

instance Functor List where
  fmap _ Nil = Nil
  fmap f (Cons x xs) = Cons (f x) (fmap f xs)

instance Applicative List where
  pure x = Cons x Nil
  Nil <*> _ = Nil
  _ <*> Nil = Nil
  Cons f fs <*> Cons x xs = Cons (f x) ((fmap f xs) <> (fs <*> xs))
```

I wrote the above code and found I must first instance `Semigroup` to let the `<>` operator work.

Can this be implemented without instance `Semigroup` first?

Comment: Of course, just provide a named concatenation function for your `List` type and use that instead of `<>`. But why?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**. You here use the `(<>)` function in your definition:

```
instance Applicative List where
    pure x = Cons x Nil
    Nil <*> _ = Nil
    _ <*> Nil = Nil
    Cons f fs <*> Cons x xs = Cons (f x) ((fmap f xs) <> (fs <*> xs))
    --                                               ^ call to the (<>) function
```

so you can replace this with a call to another function:

```
instance Applicative List where
    pure x = Cons x Nil
    Nil <*> _ = Nil
    _ <*> Nil = Nil
    Cons f fs <*> Cons x xs = Cons (f x) (append (fmap f xs) (fs <*> xs))
        where append = ...
```

Note however that here you probably have implement a different function than the one you intend here. Here you implemented a function that for two lists `[f1, f2, f3]` and `[x1, x2, x3, x4]`, will calculate a list with the "upper triangle" of the matrix of `fs` and `xs`, so this will result in `[f1 x1, f1 x2, f1 x3, f1 x4, f2 x2, f2 x3, f2 x4, f3 x3, f3 x4]`. Note that here `f2 x1`, `f3 x1` and `f3 x2` are missing.

Answer (score 0):

Well you use something called `<>` and Haskell knows that this thing (specifically the definition of `<>` that you have imported as you haven’t defined the operator anywhere) requires a semigroup. The solution is to use a different name or define it locally:

```
Cons f fs <*> xs = (f <$> xs) <> (fs <*> xs)
    where xs <> Nil = xs
          Nil <> xs = xs
          Cons x xs <> ys = Cons x (xs <> ys)
```